# Gaussian warning

Tags: gaussian

I am running an ONIOM optimization calculation on GAUSSIAN software and when I open the LOG file I get a warnig saying:

`ConnectionGlob::Parse_BINK0 failure reading archive entry`
and on other systems using the same method I get the following warning:
`unable to find dipole derivative`

What does it mean? Are there any problems with my calculations? Do I have to redo them?

Comment: Can you include the input file in your question so we can try to reproduce these messages? Unless you were specifically calculating something involving dipole derivatives, I don't think this would cause any problems for an optimization. As for the `ConnectionGlob` error, this seems to be an error coming from the program you are using to open the file, rather than the calculation itself.